# iPhone Safari scaling resolution

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, safari

I'm new to the world of web design and I've started with HTML and CSS. I've begun by building my own website from scratch and I'm currently stumped with how the design scales across different platforms.

When viewing my website on an iPhone 7, which is listed online as having a resolution of 750 x 1334, my inline-block images are able to sit next to one another in rows of 2. I don't understand how this is possible when they are set to have a height and width of 400px. I've attached a developer screenshot from chrome dev tools to show further. [Developer tools showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeCfc.jpg)

Do I have a misunderstanding of how iPhones display content? If the maximum width resolution is 750px (and only 375px according to chrome dev tool...) how is it able to display 2 400px images side by side?

Comment: It sounds like your viewport is scaling down rather than adapting. Do you have a [**viewport `<meta>` tag**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) set? Do you have any [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: Nope, I have neither of those. No responsive design attempts have been made yet. I'm trying to first understand why the default systems behave the way that they do.

Answer (score 0):

iPhones have "Retina display" which have a higher screen resolution than the "logical" resolution that you see in dev tools.

The image (content of the whole screen) is first rasterized, after that downsampled to the screen resolution and then displayed on the physical screen.

For the iPhone 7  model (and  6 and 8) scale factor is 2. 
These models have screen resolution of 750x1334 and logical resolution of 375x667.
You can find resolutions for other models [here](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) and more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html).

As for the 2 images with width of 400px displaying on the 375px with screen side by side seems like a viewport zoom "issue". 
The  of the html is not visible on the screenshot, but the "jumbotron" class on the  suggests that you used bootstrap. Perhaps you have unintentionally set the viewport when you where setting up bootstrap.